# failed to deploy smart contract on my private network

Tags: contract-development, transactions, contract-deployment, private-blockchain, contract-debugging

I created a private network of POA, and I use clef to seal blocks like this:
[image]

I have successfully run this chain becaues it can produce blocks and I can create transactions between 2 accounts, and transactions can be packed into the block successfully too. But when i want to create a smart contract on my private chain, my code is :

```
func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("./node1/geth.ipc")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(client, "successfully connected")

    file := "node1/keystore/UTC--2023-08-14T08-01-07.428821000Z--ec9607877c2df4c62a7bac8123bac9eac82f7115"

    jsonBytes, err := os.ReadFile(file)

    password, _ := os.ReadFile("./node1/password.txt")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    chainID, _ := client.ChainID(context.Background())
    Key, _ := keystore.DecryptKey(jsonBytes, string(password))
    fmt.Println(Key)

    auth, err := bind.NewTransactorWithChainID(strings.NewReader(string(jsonBytes)), string(password), chainID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    nonce, _ := client.PendingNonceAt(context.Background(), Key.Address)

    auth.Nonce = big.NewInt(int64(nonce))
    auth.GasPrice = big.NewInt(0)
    auth.GasLimit = uint64(210000)

    address, tx, instance, err := DeployStorage(auth, client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Contract pending deploy:0x%x\n", address)
    fmt.Printf("Transaction waiting to be mined:0x%x\n\n", tx.Hash())

    time.Sleep(25000 * time.Millisecond)

    value, err := instance.Retrieve(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Vaule:", value)

    }
```

the DeployStorage was produced by the Storage.sol , and I have complie the contract code,
[image]

the Storage.sol code is

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >0.7.0 < 0.9.0;
/**
* @title Storage
* @dev store or retrieve variable value
*/

contract Storage {

    uint256 value;

    function store(uint256 number) public{
        value = number;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256){
        return value;
    }
}
```

when I go run *.go, it returns

[image]

so I use eth.getTransactionReceipt to trace this tx of contract creation, and I found its transactions status is 0x0, which means it failed to complete this transaction? And it can be still found in the block, but it failed to create this contract, so what's wrong with my work? how can I successffully deploy a smart contract on my private chain?

Comment: Do not share text as image.

Comment: sorry,  I just wanna show what happened in my code@Itération122442

Comment: And it is alright. But provide it as text, not as image.